# Keras: Fading out layer or changing variable within session

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to fade a keras layer over several batches stepwise out. Therefore I wrote a custom layer "DecayingSkip". In addition I'm adding it residually to an other layer. Im trying to implement a fading out skip connection.
However the code seems not to work correctly. The model compiles and trains, but the layer activation is not faded out as expected. What am I doing wrong?

```
class DecayingSkip(Layer):
    def __init__(self, fade_out_at_batch, **kwargs):
        self.fade_out_at_batch = K.variable(fade_out_at_batch)
        self.btch_cnt = K.variable(0)
        super(decayingSkip, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, x):
        self.btch_cnt = self.btch_cnt + 1.0
        return K.switch(
            self.btch_cnt >= self.fade_out_at_batch,
            x * 0,
            x *  (1.0 - ((1.0 / self.fade_out_at_batch) * self.btch_cnt))
        )

def add_fade_out(fadeOutLayer, layer, fade_out_at_batch):
    cnn_match = Conv2D(filters=int(layer.shape[-1]), kernel_size=1, activation=bounded_relu)(fadeOutLayer)
    fadeOutLayer = DecayingSkip(fade_out_at_batch=fade_out_at_batch, name=name + '_fade_out')(cnn_match)
    return Add()([fadeOutLayer, layer])
```

Besides, in another attempt I tried to use a tensorflow variable which I changed within the session like:

```
def add_fade_out(fadeOutLayer, layer):
    fadeOutLayer = Conv2D(filters=int(layer.shape[-1]), kernel_size=1, activation='relu')(fadeOutLayer)
    alph = K.variable(1.0, name='alpha')
    fadeOutLayer = Lambda(lambda x: x * alph)(fadeOutLayer)
    return Add()([fadeOutLayer, layer])

sess = K.get_session()
lw = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("alpha:0") 
sess.run(K.tf.assign(lw, new_value))
```

This did not work either. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the solution. I changed the call function of the layer to:

```
def call(self, x):
    self.btch_cnt = K.tf.assign_add(self.btch_cnt, 1)
    K.get_session().run(self.btch_cnt)

    return K.switch(
        self.btch_cnt >= self.fade_out_at_batch,
        x * 0,
        x * (1.0 - ((1.0 / self.fade_out_at_batch) * self.btch_cnt))
    )
```